# Unable to deploy django with mod_wsgi & apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm unable to deploy my django site using mod_wsgi after a a few frustrating days of trying. Could someone sanity check these details and see if there's anything obviously wrong? This is my first Django deployment. Its been running file with python `manage.py runserver 10.10.10.214:8080` but I cannot deploy

my `wsgi.py` file in `/home/user/django/mysite` (also where my settings.py etc are)

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

my apache .conf file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /home/conf/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so #dont read into the locations too much - they are correct

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/django/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/user/django

<Directory /home/user/django/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I am forced to use a heavily pre-customized version of apache but the conf file above is included. Any help at all would be great.

Cheers, Arthur

Comment: I recommend to deploy with nginx and uwsgi ;) http://www.django-tips.com/tip/deploying-django-project-with-nginx-and-uwsgi/3/

Comment: Does the apache error log point you in any direction. The config seems about right at first glance

Comment: I might just have to look at that @doniyor

Comment: You might as well look into gunicorn / nginx - the set up is plain simple compared to apache and mod_wsgi. Only use an apache webserver if you stuck with it for some reason

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer looks like that may be the issue: `[Wed Jul 01 16:50:15 2015] [error] [client 10.78.73.27] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/user/django') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://10.10.10.214/`. Any idea how I might fix search permissions. I had already tried fixing the issue with a blanket 'chmod -R 777' on the django root dir containing code and static files

Comment: are you using apache 2.2? than the permissions shoud be: <Directory /usr/local/django/mysite>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: This could also help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451922/apache-access-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing

Comment: I am getting somewhere now @MaximilianKindshofer - seeing an error that I am much more comfortable with: `[Wed Jul 01 17:34:17 2015] [error] [client 10.78.73.27] ImportError: No module named wsgi`

Comment: You might check robs wsgi.py file below. It seams that you can't import tje wsgi module from this location and need to append its syspath also check: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango its a great resource for mod_wgsi

Comment: A home directory such as ``/home/user`` would often have restrictive permissions and not be accessible to other users. Thus it isn't enough just to make the Django project directory accessible. The home directory would also need to be accessible to the user that Apache runs as. It may be better to move the project out of your user account so you aren't mucking with the account permissions.

Comment: Just an FYI, I've never encountered permissions problems with Django apps under my `home` folder (where user is in the `www-data` group). That said, I keep my apps under a more logical place now, like `/srv/web/vh/`.

Comment: Hrmph. I am now seeing an import error - `[Thu Jul 02 17:49:15 2015] [error] [client 10.78.73.27] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named staticfiles`. I've tried importing django.contrib.staticfiles in `wsgi.py` which works fine, but it is not the source of the problem. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"

sys.path.append('/home/user/django/mysite/')
sys.path.append('/home/user/django/')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And add this to your conf, before the alias:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess <process_name> processes=2 threads=15 user=<username> display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup <process_name>
```

The process name could be "mysite.com" or whatever. The user is a Linux user.

Comment: Rob - would I be correct in saying that the <process_name> can be anything? Something logical of course. Also I believe leaving user=<username> out will use default apache child permissions

Comment: Arthur, you're probably right about both of those things. I use `user=www-data`, for example.